# Use Powershell to Consume WCF Service with wshttpbinding

Tags: c#, wcf, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to consume a WCF service using Powershell. When I use the the basichttpbinding I can consume it w/o a problem using the following commands

> $MyWcfService = New-WebServiceProxy -UseDefaultCredential -Uri "http://localhost:8733/TestService?wsdl"
>
> $MyWcfService.HelloWorld()

However when I change the binding to wshttpbinding I get the following error

> Exception calling "HelloWorld" with "0" argument(s): "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error
>   occurred on a receive."
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> - $TestService.HelloWorld()
> - ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

How do I consume a WCF service with the wshttpbinding?

Comment: Is the service at `http://localhost:8733/TestService?wsdl` set up to accept wsHttpBindings?   Can you post the service's configuration file?

Comment: yes it's setup to access wsHttpBindings, I can consume the WCF using a client written in c# w/o a problem

Comment: Any success with this?  I need to consumer WS that requires cookies for authentication, so I need to configure wsHttpBinding.